Why can I not have some template parameter deduced and some provided in this case?
Link to code: compiler_explorer
I have a templated class with three parameters: int, typename, template <typename> typename. For this class I want to provide just the first parameter, the int: eg: Obj<1>.
I am trying to have the compiler deduce the second and third parameters via the constructor.
template <typename... Args> struct dummy{};

template <int dummy_parameter, typename T, template <typename> typename S>
struct Obj 
{
    explicit Obj(S<T>* some_data) : data{ some_data } {}

    S<T>* data;
};

template <typename T, template <typename> typename S>
struct Obj2 
{
    explicit Obj2(S<T>* some_data) : data{ some_data } {}

    S<T>* data;
};

int main()
{
    dummy<double>* x;
    Obj2 obj2{ x };     // deduces the parameters
    Obj<1> obj{ x };   // doesn't deduce anymore, why?
}

How to I manage to get the second and third parameters deduced by the compiler? Is this possible?

"doesn't deduce anymore, why?..." Because Partial CTAD isn't allowed in C++. It's all or nothing.

See dupe: Partial class template argument deduction in C++17 and also Why is partial class template argument deduction impossible?
